# PHP preg_match найти слово капсом

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Необходимо найти в строке первое слово (только английский) капсом. 
Пробовал так:

```
/(?=[A-Z])([A-Z]+)/
```

Работает, EXAMPLE находит, но если есть слово с большой буквы 'Example' оно цепляет эту первую букву E только. Прошу, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить текущий паттерн для захвата слова (это от двух букв, если что) написаного КАПСОМ?

Comment: `\b` - граница слова

Comment: м? `^([A-Z]+)\b`

Comment: @teran
Спасибо, забыл про \b.
Нужно курить больше доку)

Comment: `/\b([A-Z]+)\b/u` - про юникод не забывайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте последовательность символов `\b`, обозначающих границы слова, а так же указывайте необходимую длину подстроки с помощью уточняющих квантификаторов `{2,}`*(два, и более)*:

> `'~\b[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{2,}\b~u'`

Comment: Спасибо большое!